# Update query with two post array's

Tags: php, mysqli

Making the question clearer from a previous question.

I am trying to bring an id from a hidden form on a previous page and using it as a variable as part of an update query.

The path to this point is....: 
Log in to admin area (using a different table)... 
Search 'businesses' database for entry...
Entry displays with an update button, the update button has a hidden ID... value that gets posted to this page through "submit"...

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["submituname"]))
    {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $name = $_POST["uname"];
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE businesses SET username='$name' WHERE id='$id'");

    if($query)
    {
        $msguname = "<p>Your username has now been updated.</p>";
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show the HTML code ( Where hidden ID is stored  ) ? on http://pastebin.com/ ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8V8MyXqM I have attached the pastebin. 

I have also echo $id and the ID is reaching this page without problems.

Comment: and is there any error in this script ?

Comment: You mean the hidden input field is getting the $id ? right ? ..

Comment: Yes an error. The script above posts 'Your username has now been updated.' before any update has taken place. That database also doesnt update.

Comment: The hidden field is getting the $id yes. Thanks.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LiiNU3HV

Here is the HTML for the 'submituname' form.

Comment: Now , i get it .. actually the way you are doing is not correct .. the id will be vanish after second submit in this script ..

Comment: Exactly what I thought and then I didnt know what to do next.

Comment: Have you got any ideas?

Comment: wait 5 minute , i'm posting an answer how to pass variables between two script using $_GET method ..

Comment: can you please give me the full HTML of this page ?

http://pastebin.com/LiiNU3HV ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your are doing this is not standard coding , I think you are a beginner you'll learn soon . You need to build url here , and catch the $id on adminupdate.php using $_GET method.

```
<?php
if($resultSet->num_rows > 0){
        while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
                $name = $rows ['name'];
                $type = $rows ['type'];
                $tel = $rows ['tel'];
                $add = $rows ['address'];
                $bio = $rows ['bio'];
                $email = $rows ['email'];
                $web = $rows ['web'];
                $id = $rows ['id'];

                $telns =  str_replace(' ', '', $tel);

                $output .= '<gmp_div() id= "out"> <span style="line-height: 25px">
                <h4><strong><span style= "color:#13164d;">'.$name.'</span></strong></h4>
                <div class= "out1"><p>'.$type.'</br>'.$add.'</br>About: '.$bio.'</p></div>
                <div class= "out2"><p>
                <a href="tel:$telns" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> $tel</span></a></br>
                <a href="mailto:'.$email.'" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> '.$email.'</span></a></br>
                <a href="http://'.$web.'" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> Website</span></a>
                </p></div>

                <a href="adminupdate.php?id='.$id.'">Follow</a>

                </div>';


}



?>
```

In adminupdate.php get the $id using $_GET method

This is the HTML:

```
 <tr>
                    <td><p>Username</p><input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Username" />
                    <td> <input type="hidden"  name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>"/></td>
                    <td><button type="submit" name="submituname"><p>Update</p></button></td>
                    <td><?php echo $msguname;?>
</tr>
```

This is the PHP script that you used ( a bit modified ):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["submituname"]))
    {
        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $name = $_POST["uname"];
    }

    $query = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `businesses` SET `username`='$name' WHERE `id`='$id'");

    if($query)
    {
        $msguname = "<p>Your username has now been updated.</p>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you and of course I will. I shall check soon! Do you need anything else from me?

Comment: Perfect!! Adjusted my update form and it's perfect. Thank you so much! I am getting there!!!